# Expo EAS - Application returns white screen on build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

everything works perfectly on

```
expo start
```

application works without any error.
But when I make build, it returns empty white screen. And there's not much errors, because i can not debug it.

```
npx expo run:ios --configuration Release
```

I'm using that command. My eas.json file like below:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.9.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

And I receive only empty white page.
Btw i get some errors like below, but even i destroy the error (with uninstall expo-update npm package) it still returns white screen.

```
{"code":"UpdateFailedToLoad","message":"\"channel-name\" is not allowed
to be empty. The headers \"expo-runtime-version\", \"expo-channel-name\", and \"expo-platform\" are
required. They can also be set with the query parameters \"runtime-version\", \"channel-name\", and
\"platform\".","timestamp":1681832747000,"level":"error","stacktrace"
```

Comment: If you want to run the app on ExpoGo run expo start -i and if you want to run a dev build run expo prebuild and then expo run:ios. No need for --configuration Release because you dont have a build called Release defined

Comment: @DustinSpengler ok but even that, nothing changes. because my build also crashes.